# Keyboard messing up the dialog box

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog box with a `textfield` in it. Whenever I hit the textfield, the keyboard comes up and messes up the whole UI of the dialog box.

**Attempt to fix the issue:**

I have used this in my `Scaffold`: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`. Nothing worked out.

I also tried to find something else on the Internet but no results.

**Dialog box:**

[image: Dialog box]

**Result after hitting the text field:**

[image: Resultant image]

I would like to make the dialog box go up or adjust with the keyboard.

Comment: try wrapping Square barcode  widget inside Flexible

Comment: Hey @ManishDhruw, why only bar code. Not the whole content? Do you want to my dialogbox code?

Comment: may be try both

Comment: I will update you @ManishDhruw

Comment: It is throwing a lot of error for the dialogbox @ManishDhruw. This is not a workable idea though in my case

Comment: i haven't  used dialog box yet, so cant help you i guess

Comment: Wrap your widget with SingleChildScrollView and make layout scrollable. It will solve your design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the way your dialog box is shrinking. Would it be possible to have the contents of the dialogBox be scrollable? And when the keyboard is invoke (textfield in focus) can you scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, we can. It is possible, but yeah in order to submit it you have to scroll it to see the content.

Answer (score 0):

Should hide keyboard before you dialog call.

To hide keyboard can use below code-

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onPanDown: (_) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  child: SingleChildScrollView(...),
);
```

Comment: the input is in the dialog, so suggestion to hide keyboard before dialog call does not make sense in this case